# Kafka: What is new API kafka.utils.ZkUtils Upgrading from 0.8 to 2.1

Tags: apache-kafka, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Kafka in academic project and found this class in 0.8 which is deprecated in Kafka 2.1

I am looking for help.

Where ZKUtils is deprecated.

```java
synchronized public void createTopicInZk (HETopic heTopic, int numPartitions, int replicationFactor)
{
    ZkClient zkClient = getNewZkClient();

    try {
        AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient,
                heTopic.getCompositeTopic(),
                numPartitions,
                replicationFactor,
                new Properties()
        );
    } finally {
        if (zkClient != null) zkClient.close();
    }
}
```

Then I see error like expecting ZkUtil instead of ZKClient (first argument for AdminUtils.createTopic)

So changed code to

```java
synchronized public void createTopicInZk (HETopic heTopic, int numPartitions, int replicationFactor)
{
    ZkClient zkClient = getNewZkClient();
    **ZkUtils zkUtils = ZkUtils.apply(zkClient, false);**

    try {
        AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils,
                heTopic.getCompositeTopic(),
                numPartitions,
                replicationFactor,
                new Properties()
        );
    } finally {
        if (zkClient != null) zkClient.close();
    }
}
```

This solution works but I am getting ZkUtils deprecated warning message while running. What is the new replacement for ZKUtils ?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the `AdminUtils` or `ZkUtils` classes. These are internal classes and not part of the [public APIs](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html). Using internal classes exposes you to situations like this where you code breaks because of some Kafka internal changes.

However I understand that with Kafka 0.9, there weren't public APIs supporting this feature. However it's not the case anymore!

Now you should use the AdminClient API to create topics, see [`createTopics()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#createTopics-java.util.Collection-)